Where to Pack Heating Gloves?
Where should self-heating gloves be packed? I have a pair of gloves with a builtin heat-source. They are charged via USB-C so there is most likely a lithium-ion battery in them.
Given that I will be flying Delta later today, I checked their information but the information is unclear. On this page it says:

You can bring lithium-battery powered devices as carry-on items or in checked baggage.

While on this other page it says:

Devices containing lithium metal or lithium-ion batteries (laptops, smartphones, tablets, etc.) should be transported in carry-on baggage and not placed in checked baggage.

Which one would apply to heating gloves? Normally I place battery-powered devices in carry-on but these are kind of bulky and I will be transferring to a smaller airline allows them in checked luggage.

My opinion: carry on because on checked baggage it may cause trouble on security: small device with battery. IMHO there is an higher risk to have checked baggage open, and so maybe to lose some items.. But this reasoning is unrelated to your real question.

"Devices containing lithium metal or lithium-ion batteries (laptops, smartphones, tablets, etc.) should be transported in carry-on baggage and not placed in checked baggage." - This sounds counterintuitive, at least in Europe too often they ask me to check my hand luggage, and usually with those inside. They still ask me to check in even when I explicitly told them.

The IATA guidance is here.
Provided the battery is less than 100 Wh, they are allowed in both carry-on and checked luggage, but with caveats:

PEDs, which may include electronics such as cameras, mobile phones, laptops and tablets containing batteries, when carried by passengers for personal use, should be carried in carry-on baggage.
If devices are carried in checked baggage:

measures must be taken to protect the device from damage and to prevent unintentional activation;
the device must be completely switched off (not in sleep or hibernation mode).


So there is a clearly a preference for carry-on (as it's easier to detect and contain a fire or other adverse event). If you put them in checked baggage, make sure you follow the rules given above.
Specifically:

Make sure there is no risk of the battery being punctured, compressed, or subject to any other mechanical stress
Make sure the heating element is completely off using some kind of physical switch

Also, while the TSA site does not know about "heating gloves", it knows about:

"Heating pads (electric)" (authorised in both)
"Heated Jackets/Sweaters" (authorised in both, with caveats re: spare batteries)
"Lithium batteries with 100 watt hours or less in a device" (authorised in both, with caveats for checked luggage)

The FAA guidance is here, which basically says the same:

(...)
should be carried in carry-on baggage
(...)
allowed in carry-on and checked baggage
(...)

Note that the rule is different for spare batteries which are not allowed in checked luggage and have additional rules in carry-on.

The IATA document is from February 2019. I missed the change (also considering that in 2010s with the frequent fires of Samsung Galaxy Note 7). Nice to have all the links!


Where should self-heating gloves be packed? I have a pair of gloves with a builtin heat-source. They are charged via USB-C so there is most likely a lithium-ion battery in them.

Carry-on. https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/portable-electronic-devices-with-batteries:

Devices containing lithium metal or lithium ion batteries (laptops, smartphones, tablets, etc.) should be carried in carry-on baggage.

Also see tsa.gov.
jcaron's is great, but some airport staff are unaware of the 100 Wh threshold (or it doesn't exist in some airports), e.g. my bug zapper in my checked bag got thrown away by airport security due its battery (which was much smaller than 100 Wh).

That link actually says "Most consumer personal electronic devices containing batteries are allowed in carry-on and checked baggage".

Do not post new answer. Edit the deleted one to be acceptable and request it to be undeleted.
